# Passing a vector from C# to Python

Tags: c#, python.net

1. I use Python.Net for C# interaction with Python libraries. I solve the problem of text classification. I use FastText to index and get the vector, as well as Sklearn to train the classifier (Knn).During the implementation, I encountered a lot of problems, but all were solved, with the exception of one.
   After receiving the vectors of the texts on which I train Knn, I save them to a separate text file and then, if necessary, use it.

```
    string loadKnowVec = File.ReadAllText("vectorKnowClass.txt", Encoding.Default);
    string[] splitKnowVec = loadKnowVec.Split('\r');
    splitKnowVec = splitKnowVec.Where(x => x != "").ToArray();
    for()
    { 
        keyValues_vector.Add(float.Parse(splitKnowVec[i], NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo), 1);
    }
        dynamic X_vec = np.array(keyValues_vector.Keys.ToArray()).reshape(-1, 1);
        dynamic y_tag = np.array(keyValues_vector.Values.ToArray());
        dynamic neigh = KNN(n_neighbors: 3);
        dynamic KnnFit = neigh.fit(X_vec, y_tag);
        string predict = neigh.predict("0.00889");
        MessageBox.Show("Скорее всего это: "+predict);
```

During the training of the classifier, I encountered such a problem that from c# to python, it is not values with the float type, but the value of System.Single[].

```
Python.Runtime.PythonException: "TypeError : float() argument must be a string or a number, 
not 'Single[]'
```

The stored value, at this point, of dynamic X_vec is "System.Single[]".(I think that's exactly the problem)

2.At first I tried to manually set the values of X_vec, but the error and its values were the same.
The first idea was to change the array type using the numpy library, but it didn't help, it also gave out "".

```
dynamic Xx = np.array(X_vec, dtype: "float"); 
dynamic yY = np.array(y_tag, dtype: "int");
```

Next, it was tried to create an empty array in advance and load specific values into it before changing the data type, but this also did not work.

Perhaps I do not understand the principle of the formation and interaction of the MSVS19 IDE and the python interpreter.

Comment: It's telling you that you're invoking a function that expects *one* floating-point number somewhere with an array -- so the actual problem is not `X_vec` (which is an array of `float`, as is expected) but the call site. What's the actual line you get the error on, and the full call stack?

Comment: If we use `dynamic Xx = np.array(X_vec, dtype: "float")` , then it indicates an error in this line, and if without changing the data type, then in the line `dynamic KnnFit = neigh.fit(X_vec, y_tag);`

Comment: What Python.NET version are you using? The 3.0.0 previews from NuGet should work with arrays.

Comment: My Python.Net version: pythonnet_netstandard_py39_win(2.5.2). If I understood you correctly, my version only works with List <>, 3.0.0 will work with arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue for a couple of days and each time I thought it was worth reading the documentation on python.net .
As a result, I found a solution and it turned out to be quite banal, it is necessary to represent `X_vec` not as a `float[]` , but as a `List<float>`

```
List<float> vectors = keyValues_vector.Keys.ToList();
List<int> classTag = keyValues_vector.Values.ToList();
dynamic a = np.array(vectors);
dynamic X_vec = a.reshape(-1, 1);
dynamic y_tag = np.array(classTag);
```